# Testing Watson responses containing HTML markup in Botium Box

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

I'm testing out the Botium Box service and trying to run a test of chatbot conversations within IBM Watson. When the service tries to test an utterance that results in a response/output that contains HTML markup for a URL, it fails. **Is this a bug or is there a way to use Botium Box to test and verify responses containing HTML markup for hyperlinks?** If I can't automatically test responses that contain html markup for URLs, I might as well do all the testing my hand.

Scenario: 
A user asks a question and the chatbot (IBM Watson) returns a response that contains a hyperlink. This hyperlink is embedded into the response using HTML markup. I have tried various configurations of the HTML markup code, such as moving the elements around and using apostrophes vs quotes.

The HTML markup in this case is:
`<a target="_blank" href="https://facilities.gwu.edu/heating-cooling-residential">go.gwu.edu/heatcool</a>`

When tested within IBM Watson, the response renders with a hyperlinked word. (correctly)

When tested within Botium Box live chat, it does not render as a hyperlink and instead shows the HTML markup.

When running a test in Botium Box, this utterance fails with the error:

`Error: Temperature question 2/Line 6: assertion error - Error: Line 6: FAILURE: https://facilities.gwu.edu/heating-cooling-residential">go.gwu.edu/heatcool</a> Not Found Actual: 404 Expected: 200 at Promise.all.then.results (/home/ec2-user/botium-box-dist/premium/agent/node_modules/botium-asserter-hyperlink/src/HyperLinkAsserter.js:105:31) at <anonymous> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For enabling HTML in the live chat, please enable this option in Botium Box for the chatbot:

[image]

The error message is already pretty detailed: in the Botium Box trial, there is a hyperlink checker to assert that all hyperlinks returned from the bot are actually valid links with valid responses. In this case, the HTTP error code 404 is returned.

Comment: Thank You. Looks like I can't change that in the test version so I didn't see it.